# set permissions Hibernate Validator etc. via Java policy file

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

Still getting in my raw project (established only for @Pattern exercises in @Entity without any Spring framework and servlets):

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.validation.NoProviderFoundException: Unable to create a Configuration, because no Bean Validation provider could be found ...
```

I've decided to try it with Jakarta libraries and found in hibernate operate manual point 1.1.3. "Running with a security manager" such an additional, suggested configuration lines to put in the java policy file

- vide: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-getting-started-security-manager

but before I will begin configuration tests with my `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/default.policy` file I would like to gather information: how to refer to libraries that I would like to authorize in this file for the appropriate accesses?

Should I give this direct path to the jar files or point only to the fully-qualified class name? and what is the correct syntax in `default.policy`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you think you are doing, but the error clearly says that there is no bean validation implementation available on the class-/module-path. The reason why it can't find the provider depends on your project. Maybe you didn't specify it as dependency? Anyway, if you need further help, you will have to post more information about your project and runtime setup.

Comment: How can I prove it?  There are all necessary jars in the project, the same as Spring can download. I have no error regarding any missing import. Maybe I should indicate my `EntityValidator` class in `persistence.xml` but I do not know how.

Comment: How about you debug into `javax.validation.Validation.GenericBootstrapImpl#configure` and figure out yourself why it can't find a provider. You will probably see that it tries to load the providers in `javax.validation.Validation.GetValidationProviderListAction#loadProviders` but the classloader most probably has no reference to JARs that contain a provider.